# Node version upgrade for contract deployment throws error

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs, truffle-deployment, openzeppelin-contracts

I wrote a solidity contract using version 0.4.24 using OpenZeppline-solidity version 1.12.0. This used to deploy using the Nodejs version 8.12. The Nodejs version 8 is no longer being maintained from Jan 2020, so I updated it to 12.18.3 LTS. Now the deployment throws the following error.

`truffle deploy --network development`

> throws

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Node v12.18.3

*truffle-config.js*

```
...
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.4.24",
      settings: {         
       optimizer: {
         enabled: true,
         runs: 200
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Node.js versions are mostly backward compatible, meaning that code you wrote for Node 8 will work on Node 10 or 12.*

*package.json dependencies*

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^1.12.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.42",
    "retry": "^0.12.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.24",
    "truffle": "^5.1.39",
    "web3": "^1.2.11"
  }
```

Comment: Likely some compatibility issue. Just keep using the dedicated Node version and environment for maintaining old contracts. NVM is your friend https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

Use node version 10.x or 11.x

To install node versions using nvm:

`nvm install node-v11.15.0`

or to install node v10 LTS

`nvm install node-v10.22.0`

To use the node version installed:

`nvm use 11.15.0`

or to use node v10 LTS

`nvm use 10.22.0`

Then delete the previous node modules folder and package-lock.json from the working directory.

`npm i`

`truffle deploy --network development`